# Signals and systems - Does y(n-1) affects when I check the system for linearity?

Tags: signal, linear, system, non-linear

I have the following system:
$$
y[n] = \frac{x[n]}{3}+ 2x[n-1] -y[n-1]
$$
And I have to check its linearity, but I don't know if i'm supposed to evaluate y[n-1] as if it was a x[n-1], or if I have to leave it outside the equation:
$$
y[n]=a_1g(x_1[n])+a_2g(x_2[n])
$$
In the second case I would have a linear system, and in the first case I would have a non-linear system.

Comment: Introduce the following substitution \$y[n-1]=w[n]\$ and \$x[n-1]=v[n]\$. Now consider that \$x[n]\$, \$w[n]\$ and \$v[n]\$ are inputs to the system and try to prove linearity.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to consider the \$y[n-1]\$ and \$x[n-1]\$ signals as if they were some new signals not related to \$y[n]\$ and \$x[n]\$. Introduce the following substitutions:

$$y[n-1] = w[n], \quad x[n-1] = v[n]$$

Now the original equation becomes:

$$y[n] = f(x,v,w) = \frac{1}{3}x[n] + 2v[n] - w[n]$$

Let \$y_1[n] = f(x_1,v_1,w_1)\$ and \$y_2[n] = f(x_2,v_2,w_2)\$. Then

$$y_1[n] + y_2[n] = \left(\frac{1}{3}x_1[n] + 2v_1[n] - w_1[n]\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3}x_2[n] + 2v_2[n] - w_2[n]\right)$$

which is abbreviated to:

$$y_1[n] + y_2[n] = \frac{1}{3} (x_1[n]+x_2[n]) + 2(v_1[n]+v_2[n]) - (w_1[n]+w_2[n])$$

If you compare the above equation to

$$f(x_1+x_2,v_1+v_2,w_1+w_2) = \frac{1}{3} (x_1[n]+x_2[n]) + 2(v_1[n]+v_2[n]) - (w_1[n]+w_2[n])$$

you see that the **additivity** has been proven:

$$f(x_1+x_2,v_1+v_2,w_1+w_2) = f(x_1,v_1,w_1) + f(x_2,v_2,w_2)$$

As for the **homogeneity**, the approach is similar:

$$f(\alpha x, \alpha v, \alpha w) = \frac{1}{3}\alpha x[n] + 2\alpha v[n] - \alpha w[n]$$

which is equal to

$$\alpha f(x,v,w) = \alpha \left(\frac{1}{3}x[n] + 2v[n] - w[n]\right)$$

Since system satisfies both additivity and homogeneity, it is said to be **linear**. When the system is also **time-invariant**, and this one is, it falls under category of **LTI systems** which are important for signal processing and control theory.

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting the old value of y(n) from the latest value of y(n) doesn't imply non linearity; it implies a filter type that is high-pass in nature.